# How to link a Swift module produced by another xcode project?

Tags: swift, storyboard, xcode6

I have two Xcode Projects that both have a iOS App target (they're in the same xcworkspace). If my understanding is correct, each of these iOS App targets produce a Swift Module (I'm using swift obviously). I'd like to include one of the App's storyboards in the other Xcode Project and present that storyboard when a button is clicked.

However, the storyboard's swift module doesn't seem to be included automatically. I moved the source files for some of the ViewControllers over and changed the module for them in Storyboards and that worked like a charm. Is there a way to "link against" another iOS App swift module?

Comment: No. To share code, make a _framework_. That is a module you can refer to.

Comment: @matt I think you're right, I don't believe there's a way to do what I'm suggesting. However, I'll continue to investigate for my own curiosity. Turn it into an answer and if I can't find anything, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xcode 6 way to make a linkable module is to make a *framework*. Put common code into a framework and link both apps against it. See the WWDC 2014 video on this very topic (session 416).

Comment: It would seem this is the right way to do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's a hack but this may work. Add this commands to OTHER_LDFLAGS:

```
-Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/"MyModule.swiftmodule"
```

This solution mimics Xcode-generated build command.